# how to measure angles between two planes?

Tags: modeling, measurement

[image]

in this example I want to rotate the angled mesh on the left downwards at the exact opposite angle it is currently making with the flat mesh. is there a built in tool that measures what the angle is?

Answer (score 1):

If the planes are connected, you can use the built-in *Edge Angle* measuring tool in edit mode.  Here's an example with a subdivided plane:

1. To enable the measurement, go to the *Overlay* drop down tab and select [*Edge Angle*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/editors/3dview/display/overlays.html#measurement) from the *Measurement* tab.

[image: Layout menu showing edge angle selected]

2. One way to start the measurement is to select the outside edge of one of the two faces and type <kbd>G</kbd>.  The angle will appear at the edge between the two faces:

[image: Example showing angle measurement.]